# How to insert an image into a two-column document such that the text flows from TL, BL, TR and finally BR?

Tags: floats, two-column

**I don't like the following:**

[image]

**I want the following:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[demo,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,graphicx}
\title{Foo Bar Baz}
\author{Foo Bar Baz}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}

\begin{figure}[hbpt]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{}
\caption{Foo Bar Baz}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[3]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

How to insert an image into a two-column document such that the text flows from TL (top left), BL (bottom left), TR (top right) and finally BR (bottom right)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do this, as far as I'm aware. You can't put floats inside `multicol` so that's not an option. Do you *really* need the figure right there? Wouldn't it be easier to use give your document class the `twocolumn` option and have the figure float to wherever makes sense (top or bottom of the page).

[The LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Wide_figures_in_two_column_documents) has no good advice on this issue, and I expect it's simply something that is very difficult to do.